# SailsJS: Multiple primary keys in model

Tags: mysql, sails.js

How i can made model in SailsJS with multiple primary keys? I need it to preventing [duplicates](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-handling-duplicates.htm).

Comment: By definition, a table can have only one primary key (which may be composite).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by executing query on sails bootstrap

```
Query(`
    ALTER TABLE \`word\` CHANGE \`id\` \`id\` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
    ALTER TABLE \`word\` ADD UNIQUE(\`id\`);
    ALTER TABLE \`word\` CHANGE \`projectId\` \`projectId\` INT(11) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE \`word\` CHANGE \`caseId\` \`caseId\` INT(11) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE \`word\` CHANGE \`parent\` \`parent\` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE \`word\` CHANGE \`word\` \`word\` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE \`word\` CHANGE \`wordLower\` \`wordLower\` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE \`word\` CHANGE \`negative\` \`negative\` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE \`word\` DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(\`projectId\`, \`parent\`, \`wordLower\`);
`);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems [not possible](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/109). If it suits you, you could use a simple primary key and add a UNIQUE INDEX manually.

```sql
ALTER TABLE `your_database`.`your_table` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `index_name` (`first_col` ASC, `second_col` ASC);
```

You can also add validation using [lifecycle callbacks](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks).